# Error updating Sp_Blitz to the latest version

Tags: sp-blitz

I run Blitz weekly and on SQL 2008 express server the Blitz result found that i have SP_blitz over 6 month old. When i try to update everything to the latest , this is what i get .
Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 3123 Invalid column name 'is_current_owner'.
Procedure sp_BlitzLock, Line 317 Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'. Currently I have Sp_Blitz May 20 2021 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_BlitzLock only supports SQL Server 2012 & newer.

For what it's worth, Microsoft also only supports SQL Server 2012 & newer as well.

Comment: Thank you , the server have to be upgraded soon

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, and I found that the latest First Responder Kit version where you can run "Install-All-Scripts.sql" on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance without it throwing any errors is from 2020-12-11.

Obviously the recommended course of action is to upgrade to a supported SQL Server version.